# Is there a way to move a svn repository if you don't have access to the svn server?

Tags: svn, git, unix, repository, svnadmin

I have been seeing information on how to move a repository if you have access to the server the repository is hosted on but what if you only have the login information for the repository?

Can you do a full checkout of a repository and all of its revisions and then move it to another repository?

The reason for this is because I have taken over a project but don't have access to the svn server although I have login credentials.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this using git? I think git can convert svn repositories, and all git repositories have full history so it would probably take everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/) before to dump a complete SVN repository, I didn't have server access to. It takes a while but works quite well. The resulting SVN dump can then be loaded to a different repository using `svnadmin` (inlcuding a local repository which is then synced to a remote repository using `svnsync`, e.g. Google Code).

If you plan to migrate to git later on (I'm guessing this based on your git tag), then you don't need to do it that complicated though. You can just `svn clone` the repository with git then, and push the git repository you got to some other server. Then all the information is already there (`git svn clone` does fetch the whole SVN repository too).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for

http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/

http://dukeslittleb.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/how-to-migrate-an-svn-repository-without-shell-access-to-the-existing-repository/

http://blog.sourcehosting.net/2008/11/03/dump-remote-subversion-repository/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync). Just sync the remote repository to a local one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the file history?
I bet you wont (im sure someone will say they think they do - but even then i doubt they do)
So save yourself a load of time (and disk space) and just sync to the head an check that in.
(If they want the history make sure you still have access ~ 6 months)
Keep it simple....